# What did Phoebe do with the $7,000?

Tags: friends

In S01E03 *the one with the thumb*, Phoebe gets $7,000 after she saw a thumb in her soda can. She is obviously skeptical about the money and does not want to spend it, like she gave $1,000 to the homeless woman earlier.

Later she tells Chandler she will give the money to him if he quits smoking. Did she actually give it to him?

There was never a mention of this money again, if she spent it, or saved it, or gave it to charity or to Chandler. Considering $7,000 was a big amount at that time, what did she actually do with the money?

Answer (score -4):

Like you said, the money was never mentioned again. What we do know is that Chandler smokes <s>again</s> still in S3e17 *The One with the Ski Trip*, so its extremely likely he didn’t end up with the money, perhaps giving it back to Phoebe or donating it:

> **Phoebe**: Chandler, what are you doing?
>   **Chandler**: (*Pointing at his smoke*) Oh, my god!
>   **Joey**: You’re smoking again?!
>   **Chandler**: Actually yesterday I was smoking again. Today… I’m smoking still.
>   **Phoebe**: Why would you start again after chewing all that quitting gum?

(Quote via [reasonish.com](https://reasonish.com/2019/07/04/why-chandler-owes-phoebe-7000-dollars/))

Comment: Ok is somebody going to tell me what’s wrong with this

Comment: I'm not a downvoter but this is 2.5 seasons later, and indeed indicates that Joey and Phoebe are surprised he is smoking.  If anything it indicates that they thought he'd successfully given it up.  It seems a weak deduction that he didn't end up with the money.

Comment: An answer would ideally provide positive evidence that he had been given the money - like some direct quote about it.  Without that, using some sort of deduction is fine, but if anything this would suggest the opposite conclusion.

Comment: yeah, this is not an answer, it briefly extends the question. maybe that's the reason for negative score, although i'm not down voting since i find down voting as a discouragement. If it helps, provide your answer in bold with few words, continue your explanation in the next para.